# return makes integer from pointer without a cast. Introduction to programming c++

Tags: c++, vector

So i have to make a program which compares four types of colour distibuted in a vector of 10 colors. Each time the colors compare, the vector reduces its size by one, so at the end you only have one color, but im unable to write the correct code. I know it is incomplete, but i just want for it to return something reasonable. Little help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


char decidecolor (char v[], char color, int lon);

int main (void){
    
    int lon=10;
    char v[10]= {'C','C','M','Y','C','K','K','K','M','K'};


    char color= 'M';
    
    printf ("\n el nuevo vector es %d", decidecolor(v,color,lon));
}

char decidecolor (char v[], char color, int lon){
    for (int i=0; i<lon; i++){
        if (v[i]=='C' && v[i+1]=='C'){
            v[i]='C';
            
        } 
        
        if (v[i]=='M' && v[i+1]=='M'){
            v[i]='M';
        }
        if (v[i]=='K' && v[i+1]=='K'){
            v[i]='K';
        }
        if (v[i]=='Y' && v[i+1]=='Y'){
            v[i]='Y';
        }
        if (v[i]=='C' && v[i+1]=='M' || v[i]=='M' && v[i+1]=='C'){
            v[i]='M';
        }
        if (v[i]=='C' && v[i+1]=='K' || v[i]=='K' && v[i+1]=='C'){
            v[i]='C';
        }
        if (v[i]=='M' && v[i+1]=='Y' || v[i]=='Y' && v[i+1]=='M'){
            v[i]='M';
        }
        if (v[i]=='M' && v[i+1]=='K' || v[i]=='K' && v[i+1]=='M'){
            v[i]='K';
        }
        if (v[i]=='Y' && v[i+1]=='K' || v[i]=='K' && v[i+1]=='Y'){
            v[i]='Y';
        }
        
    }
    
    return v;
}
```

Comment: is this from a book called "introduction to C++" ?!? That would be sad because the code is C

Comment: Like the error message says, your function is supposed to return an integer (a `char`, to be precise) but you are returning a pointer value (a `char*`). The message is telling you that this is almost definitely a mistake. Note that if, as you say, the array contains only characters of one "color" after the loop, then it should be sufficient to return `v[0]`. And if you want to print a char value as an actual character, use `%c` instead of `%d`

Comment: There are no vectors in your code only arrays. You cannot change the size of an array, so your approach to this problem cannot work. It would be an easier problem if you really did use a vector, because you can change the size of a vector.

Comment: Here's a tip on how to do this with arrays. Notice in your function you **never** change the value of `lon`. Write some more code but this time change the value of `lon` and return **the new value of lon** from the function. Don't try to return the array, that's not necessary and not legal. And go back to your book to try and understand how arrays really work in C++. You need to understand how arrays, functions and **pointers** all work together.

Comment: Consider the range of your for loop, i runs to lon-1, but i+1 will go one beyond the size of your string.
You might want to use std::string (or std::vector<char>) instead of  character arrays like char v[10]= {'C','C','M','Y','C','K','K','K','M','K'}; Then you don't have to pass the length of the array seperatly. Unlike what john said, If possible try to solve your problem without using pointers

Comment: Most of the code makes no sense: `if (v[i]=='C' ...) { v[i]='C'; }` It already is `'C'`, you just tested for that. That pattern repeats for about 80% of the `if`s. And `color` is never used.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, only the ones that actually did, i was able to make it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void escribirvector (char v[], int lon, char color);
void decidecolor (char v[], int lon, char color);


int main (){
    
    int lon=10;
    char v[]= {'C','C','M','Y','C','K','K','K','M','K'};
    char color= 'M';
    int i;
    
    escribirvector (v, lon, color);

    while (i<lon){
    printf("\n");
    decidecolor (v, lon-1, color);
    lon--;
    }
    printf ("\n");
    
    if (color == v[i]){
        printf ("1\n");
    }
    else {
        printf ("0\n");
    }
}


void escribirvector(char v[], int lon, char color){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<lon; i++){
    printf ("%c ", v[i]);
        }
        
    }

void decidecolor(char v[], int lon, char color){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<lon; i++){
        if (v[i]=='C' && v[i+1]=='C'){
            v[i]='C';
        
        } 
        
        if (v[i]=='M' && v[i+1]=='M'){
            v[i]='M';
        }
        if (v[i]=='K' && v[i+1]=='K'){
            v[i]='K';
        }
        if (v[i]=='Y' && v[i+1]=='Y'){
            v[i]='Y';
        }
        if (v[i]=='C' && v[i+1]=='M' || v[i]=='M' && v[i+1]=='C'){
            v[i]='M';
        }
        if (v[i]=='C' && v[i+1]=='K' || v[i]=='K' && v[i+1]=='C'){
            v[i]='C';
        }
        if (v[i]=='M' && v[i+1]=='Y' || v[i]=='Y' && v[i+1]=='M'){
            v[i]='M';
        }
        if (v[i]=='M' && v[i+1]=='K' || v[i]=='K' && v[i+1]=='M'){
            v[i]='K';
        }
        if (v[i]=='Y' && v[i+1]=='K' || v[i]=='K' && v[i+1]=='Y'){
            v[i]='Y';
        }
        printf("%c ",v[i]);
        }
    }
```